# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Index' (aka 'String.CharacterView.Index')

Tags: string, swift

Code:

```
let x: String = ("abc".substringFromIndex(1))
print(x)
//func tail(s: String) -> String {
//    return s.substringFromIndex(1)
//}
//print(tail("abcd"))
```

This works as expected.

But if I uncomment the last 4 lines, then I get:

```
Error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Index' (aka 'String.CharacterView.Index')
```

Really weird.

Comment: I am describing a strange behavior, not just asking for how to get the tail of a string. This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the subscripting functions in `String` no longer operate on ints, but on the inner `Index` type:

```
extension String {
    public typealias Index = String.CharacterView.Index

    //...

    public subscript (i: Index) -> Character { get }
```

So you need to grab some `Index` values. You can achieve this by obtaining the first index in the string (aka the index of the first character), and navigate from there:

```
func tail(s: String) -> String {
    return s.substringFromIndex(s.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
}
```

Note that the above code no longer compiles in the latest Swift version, I'll leave for historical purposes and for people stuck in earlier Swift.

These days we can write something along the lines of

```swift
extension String {
    var tail: String { String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: 1)...]) }
    // or
    var tail: String { String(self[index(after: startIndex)...]) }
    // or even this
    var tail: String { String(dropFirst()) }
}
```

Comment: extension String . . .    does not compile.  Bottom line gets error:  "xpected '{' to start getter definition

Comment: @DougNull which of the three `tail` definitions have you tried? All three compile fine on my side.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4:

```
func tail(s: String) -> String {
    return String(s.suffix(from: s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)))
}
```